# TaskDialog default button

Tags: windows-7, messagebox, taskdialog, windows-api-code-pack

stackoverflow just works faster :)
I'm using the [Windows® API Code Pack for Microsoft® .NET Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) to access Windows 7 API and I want to change my old [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx) to [TaskDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787471(VS.85).aspx). 
One thing I cannot find is the default button of the dialog. Is there a way to set it? what about a work around?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Default property on a control under the taskbased dialog you can set to true. From the sample (Samples\TaskDialogDemo\CS\TaskDialogDemo) that ships with it:

```
TaskDialog tdEnableDisable = new TaskDialog();
tdEnableDisable.Cancelable = true;
tdEnableDisable.Caption = "Enable/Disable Sample";
tdEnableDisable.InstructionText = "Click on the buttons to enable or disable the radiobutton.";

enableButton = new TaskDialogButton("enableButton", "Enable");
enableButton.Default = true;
enableButton.Click += new EventHandler(enableButton_Click);
```

If you run the demo, click Enable/Disable sample and then press Enter a few times you will see that the two buttons take turns being the default.